# how to make bootstrap accessible across projects

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a general question about installing Bootstrap (the compiled and minified CSS). The documentation suggests dropping this set of files into a project. I've done this and am using Bootstrap successfully.

I'm starting another project, so should I reinstall bootstrap.min.css in that directory as well, or can I move my existing installation to a library type location so that it's accessible to all projects, and modifying the bootstrap call ("css/bootstrap.min.css") to include the full pathname?

In short, what's the best practice for locating and accessing the compiled Bootstrap files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution, in my mind, is to use a CDN: a server where bootstrap.min.css is already stored (http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ for example).

In fact it's even better, there are lots of servers where it is stored, so wherever is the user of the website, he will get bootstrap.min.css really fast.

And it helps your server to avoid sending bootstrap.min.css which is relatively enormous. You will avoid useless consumption of bandwidth.